A boundary value problem for differential inclusions
Given a finite family $(\varphi_k)_{1 \le k \le K}$ of smooth scalar functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and two points $a, \, b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, I am interested in conditions such that there exists a smooth path $\gamma:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ (wlog with $\|\dot{\gamma}(\cdot)\| = 1$) such that
$$
\forall \, t \, \forall k \, \nabla \varphi_k(\gamma(t)) \cdot \dot{\gamma}(t) \le 0 \; \text{and} \;  \gamma(0) = a, \, \gamma(1) = b \, . 
$$
This is a differential inclusion, since for all $t$ $\dot{\gamma}(t)$ must be in a closed convex cone that depends  on $\gamma(t)$.
The question is (I think) interesting in its own right. My specific goal is to find paths from $a$ to $b$ such that $t \mapsto \varphi_k(\gamma(t))$ is non-increasing on $[0,1]$ for all $k$. Clearly $\varphi_k(a) \ge \varphi_k(b) \, \forall \, k$ is a necessary condition. The problem is expected to become easier if additionally $b$ is close to $a$.
I am willing to settle for special cases, such as $n = 2$ and all $\varphi_k$ being quadratic functions.
Any comments and pointers are appreciated.
